# Javascript arithmetic operators in string array

Tags: javascript, math

I have following array.

```
var signs = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
```

And following variables to add with each sign above in the array.

```
var right_digit = 1;
var left_digit = 5;
```

Can I do something like below in JS?

```
var answer = left_digit sign[0] right_digit;
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Every implementation of such is slower than `1 + 5`.

Comment: It's a game where I need to randomly select the sign.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to avoid eval you can do something like:

```
var signs = {
    '+': function(op1, op2) { return op1 + op2; },
    ...
};

var answer = signs['+'](left_digit, right_digit);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this, but you can make a function which does that.

```
function action(a, b, c) {
    switch (c) {
        case "+":
            return a+b;
        case "-":
            return a-b;
        case "*":
            return a*b;
        default:
            return a/b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` if you want dynamically evaluate operators in that way:

```
var answer = eval(right_digit + sign[0] + left_digit);
```

Note that the use of `eval is not recommended because of potentional security issues (if the data is untrusted) and slow because the code has to be analysed each time it's executed.

A better way would be using a `switch` like this:

```
function calculate(a, operator, b) {
    switch (operator) {
      case "+":
        return a + b;
      case "-":
        return a - b;
      case "*":
        return a * b;
      case "/":
        return a / b;
    }
}
var answer = calculate(right_digit, sign[0], left_digit);
```

Comment: @AlienWebguy It's one of the *possibilities*, I do not *recommend* it.

Comment: To be fair when I made my comment, `eval()` was the entirety of your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can using eval:

```
var answer = eval(left_digit + sign[0] + right_digit);
```

Answer (score 0):

A safe `eval` solution (will filter digits and sign, and throw an error if it isn't in that format):

```
function calculate(expr) {
    var matches = /^(\d+)([+\-*/])(\d+)$/.exec(expr);

    if(!matches) {
        throw "Not valid";
    }

    return eval(matches[1] + matches[2] + matches[3]);
}

calculate('2*4'); // 8
```

So you can do:

```
calculate(left + sign + right);
```